# VNC Server Security

Tags: 14.04, ssh, encryption, vnc

> First, we need to make sure VNC server only listens on localhost.

What is the meaning of this line will it listen remote connection when we onfigure it to listen localhost only?

> Recommended Step - Secure your VNC server session with encryption. A
>   basic VNC server setup has no encryption, which makes it vulnerable to
>   snooping.
>
> We will create an SSH tunnel with Putty and connect to VNC via this
>   tunnel.
>
> First, we need to make sure VNC server only listens on localhost.
>
> Edit /etc/init.d/vncserver and add -localhost to OPTIONS:

I am not able to understand the meaning of this can someone explain

> OPTIONS="-depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY} -localhost"

Comment: I guess it's to set display size

Comment: But its saying it will listen only localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-localhost` option (which is probably actually passed by the VNC server wrapper to an underlying `Xvnc` command) tells the server to only accept incoming connections that originate - or at least appear to originate - on the same server. From `Xvnc --help`:

```
localhost      - Only allow connections from localhost (default=0)
```

The port (by default, port `5900+n` where `n` is the number of the display set using the `:{DISPLAY}` variable in your example) will appear **closed** when probed from outside e.g. using `nmap`

```
$ nmap 192.168.1.16 -p 5901

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-06-04 12:47 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.16
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5901/tcp closed vnc-1
```

In this configuration, the only way to connect to the VNC service is via *tunneling* the VNC traffic over an open port/service, typically the - more secure - SSH service. This is done because raw VNC traffic is unencrypted and the native VNC password-based authentication scheme is weak.

Comment: Right now i am connecting VNC server from my location by TightVNC viewer after this change ,can it will allow me to login?

Comment: You would need to install `openssh-server` (or similar) on the VNC server machine and set up a tunnel for your VNC connection. If you _only_ have remote access to the machine, make **sure** you have configured and tested SSH thoroughly before you apply the `-localhost` option - else you may lock yourself out.

Comment: Hmm thanks Better not to make changes right now as i am newbie i do not want any big trouble for development

Comment: Just be aware that externally open VNC ports __will__ get attacked

Comment: Do you have any Step guide how to make changes for SSH so system should be safe from attacks