# Too many authentication failures VNC server and many connection with different ip

Tags: xubuntu, vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

I wanted to connect to this and get me this error Too many authentication failures VNC server.

i user `pgrep vnc` and kill all process id , and run vncserver but i received the same error,
Inside the vnc log server I saw things that are different from my IP and in a minute I see several logs with different IPs, what is this problem ? Has the server been attacked ?How can I stop them?

```
04/11/20 12:32:49 Got connection from client 5.189.156.185
04/11/20 12:32:49 Using protocol version 3.3
04/11/20 12:32:49 Too many authentication failures - client rejected
04/11/20 12:32:49 Client 5.189.156.185 gone
04/11/20 12:32:49 Statistics:
04/11/20 12:32:49   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0

04/11/20 12:32:49 Got connection from client 62.171.165.29
04/11/20 12:32:49 Using protocol version 3.3
04/11/20 12:32:49 Too many authentication failures - client rejected
04/11/20 12:32:49 Client 62.171.165.29 gone
04/11/20 12:32:49 Statistics:
04/11/20 12:32:49   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0

04/11/20 12:32:49 Got connection from client 62.171.188.224
04/11/20 12:32:50 Using protocol version 3.3
04/11/20 12:32:50 Too many authentication failures - client rejected
04/11/20 12:32:50 Client 62.171.188.224 gone
04/11/20 12:32:50 Statistics:
04/11/20 12:32:50   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0

04/11/20 12:32:51 Got connection from client 5.189.156.185
04/11/20 12:32:51 Using protocol version 3.3
04/11/20 12:32:51 Too many authentication failures - client rejected
04/11/20 12:32:51 Client 5.189.156.185 gone
04/11/20 12:32:51 Statistics:
04/11/20 12:32:51   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
```

I receive more than 20 of these errors in 1 minute with different IPs
thanks

Comment: I'd recommend configuring the VNC server to listen only on the loopback interface, and only permitting access via an SSH tunnel - see for example [VNC Server Security](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476583/vnc-server-security) and [Disallow VNC if not via a SSH tunnel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620769/disallow-vnc-if-not-via-a-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: @steeldriver thank babe

Answer (score 0):

That's expected in public domain, there are many scanners and bot for different aims including attacks.

To minimize it:

- Change the default port to one too far from know ranges
- Allow only the IP's from your country if you are not using a VPN yourself.